# How can I exclude results from graph query?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&access_token=2227470867|2.AQDzzvizJdnQFGlQ.3600.1315422000.0-100002485550696|SUNASlYr-pHh7ooE2c_omSxIhbU <---- returns all users with the name mark.

How can I do the opposite? How can I EXCLUDE all users named Mark?

I tried q!= and q<> but that did't work.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You will have to run the filter after you get the results.